# Xamarin.Forms: Using open source code instead of the nuget package to debug

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget

I am using this nuget package

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

It is available for both ios and android in pcl.

I am using it to make videos in my app.

Unfortunately, it has issues on iOS that are inside the project, not inside my code.

I am therefore trying to debug the project, not just implement the nuget library.

It does work fine on Android, so all I want to change is the iOS part.

Unfortunately, I dont know how to insert the same library when it isnt a nuget package but just the solution and also how to then adress it from pcl code.
I havent found a solution on google, but probably I dont know how to describe the problem well enought.

How can I debug an open source nuget package?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download or clone the src code,
2. Go to your project in VS,
3. Right click on your solution, choose **Add -> Existing project**,
4. Navigate to *MediaPlugin-master\src\Media.Plugin* and choose Media.Plugin.csproj file,
5. Right click on your iOS project (or whatever project where you use the plugin), choose **Add -> Reference**,
6. Check Media.Plugin and click **OK**,
7. Now you should be able to use the plugin in your project code after adding `using Plugin.Media;` (and the code of the plugin will be available to you).

Comment: @innom Were you able to include open source code into your project like I described here? Please let me know by [accepting/upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you did. Otherwise, please leave the feedback.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will try soon enough and follow up on you :)

Comment: Hey you. It seems to be working right, however; by just implementing the whole project, I know have references to UWP and TIZEN. UWP doesnt seem to work at all. I tried exlucing this from the project but it still doenst compile (missing uap). Also the dependencies in the dependency folder are still there. How can I get rid of them? I only need the iOS and Android part...

Comment: Ok, i fixed it. in the cs proj file, i had to remove all unwanted dependencies. One more thing: dont forget to also add dependency into the client project